# How to speed up binary calls?

Tags: python, binary, call

Actually I'm using a dictionary tagger which is only distributed as binary file. It gets a string as input, then prints results. I found a wrapper in python that uses `Popen`, which works well, but each call takes 1000ms to complete (is input-independent). I would like to speed it up because I need to call this process lots of times.

A good way would be to keep the process alive during the whole execution of my python program, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is a part of the wrap code

```
_input = sentences #Actually a string with "\n" escapes

p = Popen([self._cmd_path],
                shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate(_input)

# Check the return code.
if p.returncode != 0:
    print stderr
    raise OSError('Command Failed')

_output = stdout.decode(encoding)

#...other elaborations with the output
```

This is the script that I call:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set paths

BIN=xxx/bin
CMD=xxx/cmd
LIB=xxx/lib

OPTIONS="-opt1 -opt2 -opt3"

EXAMPLER1=${CMD}/file1.perl
EXAMPLER2=${BIN}/binary-file
EXAMPLER3=${LIB}/file2
EXAMPLER4=${LIB}/file3

$EXAMPLER1 -i -a $EXAMPLER4 $* |
$EXAMPLER2 $OPTIONS $EXAMPLER3
```

Comment: Does your binary expect multiple inputs, i.e. when you run it directly does it wait for your input, processes it, and then waits for the next input, etc.?

Comment: No, it terminates. By the way i forgot to mention that my program calls a shell script that calls my binary. I'll try to edit the question and past the script

Comment: It seems that you're using Perl as an intermediary, piping its processing to your final binary - that surely adds a significant overhead. Try moving your Perl logic to Python to avoid loading the Perl interpreter and call your binary directly. Second, if your binary terminates immediately there is no point in keeping a subprocess open - you'll have to create a new one anyway (and it will close, anyway). In that case the only speed up you can muster is not to use `shell=True` in your `Popen()` call.

Comment: @zwer Unfortunately reworking the perl script is too much work will take too much time for me right now. I was thinking about inserting a loop in the `$EXAMPLER1 -i -a $EXAMPLER4 $* |
$EXAMPLER2 $OPTIONS $EXAMPLER3`, so it will be a simple write in the buffer and read results looped every time. The only problem is that i don't know how to read/write without terminating the process.

Comment: Your slowdown doesn't occur because of Python's initiation of a subprocess, but because when you call it it first needs to initialize `sh` to execute your shell script, then initialize `perl` to execute your Perl script and then finally call your binary. If any of the links in that chain terminates after execution, you need to call it again incurring the same costs. It's not Python that's adding the processing time - it's mostly having to reinitialize the Perl interpreter and your binary. And you have to do that if they expect input as arguments and terminate after each call.